# Collada skeleton hierarchy

Tags: c++, opengl, collada

The collada skinning equation is the following:

```
v += {[(v * BSM) * IBMi * JMi] * JW}
```

- n
  : The number of joints that influence vertex v
- BSM: Bind-shape matrix
- IBMi: Inverse bind-pose matrix of joint i
- JMi: Transformation matrix of joint i
- JW: Weight of the influence of joint i on vertex v

So far I understand. What I do not understand is how this applies when a particular bone is son of another bone.

Should I do this?

```
v += {[(v * ParentBSM * BSM) * Parent IBMi * IBMi *  ParentJMi * JMi] * ParentJW * JW}
```

Or, what do I have to do so that the transformations of the children are done well in relation to the parents?

Comment: For skinning, hierarchy must be flattened. Usually, it happens during current pose calculation.

Comment: Excuse me, could you give an example?

Comment: The simplest way to store animations is to store a set of transformations of each bone in parent space for each frame. To render it you pick a frame to render (or you could blend between two frames). Next step would be to flatten hierarchy. Usually, bones stored as an array with parent bone always preceding its children. So, to flatten hierarchy you need to multiply bone transformation by its parent transformation.

Comment: I am going to try. Thank you very much for your response, friend